# Auto disqualify a Lead after 5 days

Tags: workflow, process-builder, visual-workflow

My Requirement: For existing/New Lead when Auto_disqualify__c field is checked, then I should disqualify this Lead in 5 business days if its not acted in meantime i.e. disqualify it if status is Open on 5th day.

Process Builder Sol: In criteria I tried to check for Auto_disqualify__c = True and then in immediate Action I am assigning Today() value in date field (Dt_Start_Auto_Disq__c). In Scheduled Action, set time for Action to Execute, I am giving 0 days after 5_Business_days__c (a formula field that considered Sat and Sun on Dt_Start_Auto_Disq__c field). On the Scheduled Action, update record I am just changing Status = Disqualified after performing Status check if its Open.

The issue is process building does all the above but during the 5 days when Lead is converted to Contact then I get below error:

> Error: Unable to convert lead that is in use by workflow

Is there any workaround or other fix besides Apex?

Comment: Did you try time based workflows?

Comment: @RahulSharma, No I didn't try WF, I assume that it will also throw similar issues.

Comment: It should not ideally

Comment: @RahulSharma, I received the same error when I used WF:
Error: Unable to convert lead that is in use by workflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching I found that only using apex code we can achieve it. 
More info: If the lead record is in the time based action queue then we cannot convert to a lead. Per documentation its nature of the process builder time dependent action. Again the workaround is Auto_disqualify__c to unflag by user before converting which is manual step. So thru declarative I couldn't achieve it.

Comment: This isn't really an answer. What did you do, exactly?

Comment: @AdrianLarson, if the lead record is in the time based action queue then we cannot convert to a lead. Per documentation its nature of the process builder time dependent action. Again the workaround is Auto_disqualify__c to unflag by user before converting which is manual step. So thru declarative I couldn't achieve it.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to clarify, rather than responding via comments.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [this Help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Unable-to-convert-lead-that-is-in-use-by-workflow-1327109102982), this is expected behavior if:

> there is a time-based workflow action pending that is related to the Lead.
>
> This can be tracked down by going to Setup | Monitoring | Time-Based Workflow. Then filter on criteria related to the Lead record that caused the error to see which workflow is implicated.

You will need to clear the Auto_disqualify__c checkbox and save the record before attempting to convert, which will remove the record from the Time-Based Workflow queue. This can either be done by user training (perhaps facilitated by a Quick Action), or a Visualforce page that overrides the Convert button and does the same.

Comment: appreciate your input but we want to implement without customization (VFP). Also if users forget to uncheck the  Auto_disqualify__c checkbox then it just throws unfriendly error. Also is there a way to check 5 business days that includes company holidays and weekend? I know we can create Company holidays but not sure how to use the same in formula field or in process builder.